# Why am i getting different asset amount using algorand Indexer vs daemon?

Tags: smartcontracts, algorand

So I created a new **ASA (AKA: Algorand Standard Asset)** and set the total amount of that asset to be maximum.

Here's a quick snippet of how I did it:

```
const UINT64_MAX: bigint = BigInt('18446744073709551615');
```

Now, When I **check how many tokens asset creator has with Algorand's Daemon API**

```
curl http://localhost:8980/v2/accounts/3IELQKOD...3C5IB3BP4V4A/assets
```

I get it exactly right as: **18446744073709551615**

But **when i check it with the indexer in the sdk its something different**.

It shows **total assets as "18446744073709552000"** to be exact which is not true.

What am i doing wrong here or this is error in library?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set your client to support **big int** or mixed.

as JS Only supports 2^^53

[image]

You can easily **set it by setting IntDecoding method** for all [JSON requests created by client here.](https://algorand.github.io/js-algorand-sdk/classes/Indexer.html#setIntEncoding)